# Browser previous button and modal window

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, browser, fancybox, browser-history

I need the following functionality when I open any modal window or look at photos (fancybox), previous button in browser should show me the page from which I opened the modal window or photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer:

1. For fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/R82gF/
2. For modal window work with `history.pushState` OR `history.replaceState`, http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state